# Paths after compiling typescript

Tags: typescript

Here is my folder structure

```
/js 
    /dev
        /admin
            app.component.ts
    /public
tsconfig.json
```

Here is my tsconfig.json file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "./js/public",
    "rootDir": "./js/dev",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Problem is that structure after compile is:

```
/js 
    /dev
        /admin
            app.component.ts
    /public
        /js
            /dev
                /admin
                    app.component.js
tsconfig.json
```

And I want

```
/js 
    /dev
        /admin
            app.component.ts
    /public
        /admin
            app.component.js
tsconfig.json
```

Comment: How are you running tsc?

Comment: phpStorm is running it

Comment: tsc is tricky for that kind, imo, not sure about recent versions

Answer (score 1):

1. Move your `tsconfig.json` in `'/js/dev/'`
2. Edit your `outDir` property to `'../public'`

Comment: Still the same - nothing changes. I'm using phpstorm